# Android Studio - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement a high score function in my app and I have created an int variable of score, but when I try to call it in another class, I keep getting "cannot resolve symbol 'score'".

```
 int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);
    scoreLabel.setText(score + "");

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Game_Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = settings.getInt("High_Score", 0);

    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() > highScore){
        highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + score);

        //save
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("High_Score", score);
        editor.commit();
    }else {
        highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + highScore);
    }


}
```

Then I have the below code in a class where I call the function but that variable 'score' keeps showing as cannot resolve symbol. What can I do?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), scoreKeeper.class);
            intent.putExtra("score", score);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Bear in mind I am a beginner so it could be something easy that I have missed.
Thanks.

Comment: make sure score is set as global variable in your class

Comment: Keep variable score as a class level (global) variable, if both codes are on separate methods

Comment: Any update for this question ?

Comment: @ZeroOne adding a global variable did solve my problem, but since I have a chronometer and I want to return that value as the user's highscore I have run into other problems. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your string, there should be a placeholder : `%1$s`

Here *%1* is the placeholder number, and *$s* is because it is a string.

Learn more here : [Stiling Strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) in section *Formating Strings*

Answer (score 0):

Set `score` as global variable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private int score; // set as global

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              .......
    }
 }
```

Don't forget to remove the `int` in line

```
 int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);
```